# одновременно проигрывать видео и ожидать подключения от клиентов python 2.7

Tags: python, сервер, raspberry-pi

У меня  pi 3. Она воспроизводит  видео по запросу клиента. Хочу сделать, чтобы пока клиенты не подключились разбери воспроизводила "фоновое видео", а после подключения клиента, прерывает "фоновое видео" и запускал видео запрошенное клиентам. Проблема в том что q, addr = s.accept() останавливает программу не дает выполняться дальше пока не подключиться клиент. Мне нужно, что бы разбери периодически проверяла, клиентов, а в остальное время занималась проигрыванием видно и прочими делами. Заранее спасибо

```
import string
import subprocess
host = "127.0.0.2"

print host
port = 7771
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket Made"
s.bind((host,port))
print "Socket Bound"
s.listen(5)
print "Listening for connections..."
q, addr = s.accept()
print q
data = s.recv(1024)
if data == "2"
 playShoppingcart=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','/home/pi/2.mp4'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)

if data == "1"
 playShoppingcart=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','/home/pi/1.mp4'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
print "3"
s.close()
```

---

Можно это сделать pthread. В одной слушателя запустить в другой видео проигрывать?

Comment: Плеер умеет рекурсивные плейлисты?

Comment: Использую  omxplayer. вроде бы не умеет